# Persistant access token across multiple ios devices?

Tags: ios, facebook

I need to be able to get the same access token when a user signs in using facebook across multiple iOS devices. Currently [[Facebook activeSession]accessToken] returns a different token depending on which device the user is using. Is there a way to have the same token returned ie 1 token per user per app, rather than 1 token per user per device?

Many thanks

Jules

Comment: Why do you need the exact same token? The tokens, although different, would still identify the same user?

Comment: well, the idea was (server side) to use the token as a unique id for the user so that when the users signed in, regardless of device) we knew who was who. I now think this may not actually work in practise though.

Answer (score 2):

Ref your answer to my comment, why don't you use the token you have obtained to fetch the facebook user id, and use that as an identifier in your application instead. That way, it doesn't matter what token you're getting, as it belongs to the same user anyway.

Comment: Yes this will work of course, it was more a case of 'can it be done with the jus the token' (as this is how the server currently is built). Thanks

Comment: "offline" tokens are no longer supported by Facebook anyway, so there's really no guarantee that you'll get the same token even on the same device. And your user might de-authorize your app, and if he/she authorizes again, the token might have changed. But the user id won't. Maybe this resource can be useful: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: Thinking about it.... is that not a bit of a security issue... as its very easy for someone to get a facebookId. We really wanted something that facebook returns (i.e. the user must have input there login details to retrieve).

Comment: To get a valid token, the user has to be authenticated by Facebook. You can use the authenticated token to get the id of the user with the Facebook graph API.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use iCloud to sync these access tokens assuming you don't want the user to sign in multiple times across their iOS devices, since there's no way for facebook to know you're the 'same' person.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I dont mind the user having to 'sign in' multiple times across devices, my issue is that when they do this Facebook gives me a new access token for each device. I want to use the access token as a unique id somehow to identify my users. So in summary I want users to sign in on any ios device and get the same token back. Does that make sense?